# Transfer Data from A Widget Search To A SEO Tool I am using my Site

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, search

I have a WordPress site at [www.itzfizz.com](http://www.itzfizz.com) and have this custom SEO tool on this page https://itzfizz.com/seo-analyzer/ which basically tells the user the different ways to improve the content of  a page/blog

I am trying to create a sidebar widget on my blog posts, where if a user types in their site, the query transfers from the search on the blog sidebar onto the SEO analyzer search bar.

I've used

```
<form method="get" action="https://itzfizz.com/seo-analyzer/?p=text">
  <input type="text" name="keyword" />
</form>
<button type="submit">Analyze Website</button>
```

but the query isn't transferred to the SEO analyzer page (Search Box) as the URL is static, can someone recommend options I can follow.

Thanks a ton

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a parameter named `p` and one named `keyword`, when the actual parameter name of the input field in the _real_ form on that page is `url`?

Comment: Ohh I see, I am not sure how to do that, can you please help me out with the get function here.

Comment: Remove the `p` parameter from the action URL (if that does not serve any actual purpose), and rename the input field to `url` …?

Comment: Doesn't work guys, if you guys can help me with a proper form code which works. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to fix:

1. The `p` parameter should be removed.
2. The `url` parameter which is the URL of the website to be analysed is missing in your form.
3. The submit button is outside the form, so it doesn't do anything
4. The `output` and `ref` parameters are missing. Since they are fixed they can just be hardcoded as hidden.

Here's the complete code for the form.

```
<form method="get" action="https://itzfizz.com/seo-analyzer/">
  <input type="hidden" name="output" value="html"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="https://itzfizz.com/seo-analyzer/"/>
  <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="https://www.yoursite.com" />
  <button type="submit">Analyze Website</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is perfect works great. The parameters helped

Comment: If works, please mark it as accepted answer so it's clear for other people reading this thread.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Marked as the accepted answer. Thanks a ton again. This was very helpful